# iOS - Stanford Tutorial - CoreDataTableViewController - Licence

Tags: ios, core-data, licensing

**Overview:**

Stanford iOS tutorials contains an implementation (header + implementation file) to help use the table view while using core data.

**link** - http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall

**File Name** - *CoreDataTableViewController.zip* (contains the below mentioned 2 files)

- *CoreDataTableViewController.h*
- *CoreDataTableViewController.m*

It contains the following text in both the files:

```
//  CoreDataTableViewController.h
//
//  Created for Stanford CS193p Fall 2011.
//  Copyright 2011 Stanford University. All rights reserved.
```

**Question**

1. can I use the 2 files in my iOS app ?
2. should I check with someone from stanford ?
3. should I leave the above mentioned comments as it is ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the page you downloaded them from has this:

"This work by Stanford University is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 United States License."

So you can use it for research & learning, but not for commercial purposes.

Here's more detail on that licence:
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/

Answer (score 8):

CoreDataTableViewController is just a bunch of code copied from Apples documentation.. If you follow the lectures, this is pointed out by Paul Hegarty.. You could just copy and paste the same information from the documentation into you own class and sub-class it..

Comment: thanks, yeah I just realised it, much of it is available with apple's documentation :D

Comment: In the lecture at 1:18 the Professor says there are only 2 methods he wrote that are mostly logging. You can take those out if you are worried.

Comment: Is it legal to copy the code from apples documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I made this new Core Data wrapper for iOS in Swift - https://github.com/tadija/AERecord

It has Swift version of CoreDataTableViewController, and CoreDataCollectionViewController also.

Beside that you can use it to setup Core Data stack like this:

```
AERecord.setupCoreDataStack()
```

Access context for current thread like this:

```
AERecord.defaultContext
```

Save context like this:

```
AERecord.saveContext()
```

Create fetch requests like this:

```
NSManagedObject.create()

NSManagedObject.firstOrCreateWithAttribute("city", value: "Belgrade")

NSManagedObject.deleteAll()

let predicate = ...
NSManagedObject.firstWithPredicate(predicate)

NSManagedObject.allWithAttribute("year", value: 1984)
```

And much more... I hope it will be useful for someone.